# Mapbox not returning voice instructions, causing Android app to crash

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

We are seeing a spike in Android users who are getting this error which crashes the app:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.mapbox.navigator.VoiceInstruction.getSsmlAnnouncement()' on a null object reference

I think this is due to the Mapbox API not sending voice instructions.

It looks like this first started happening yesterday (19th August from 22:30 UTC to 23:36 UTC) and then again today (20th August since 07:44 UTC).

Comment: Could you please include an example of the code that is generating this error?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting this issue. We’ve tracked it down to a change in the Directions API on the server side that was rolled back around 05:00 UTC on August 20th: https://status.mapbox.com/incidents/v43rj0fm0hkj . Can you please confirm that you're no longer experiencing the issue?

Kayla Bauhaus-Ness
(Mapbox Support)